# trouble converting a editable to a string in an alertdialog that saves using fileoutput

Tags: android, concatenation, android-alertdialog, fileoutputstream

In my alertdialog the user enters a comment on a Edittext.  When I convert the Editext to an editable then save the editable, it works.  However when I try to concat it with other values into a string, it does not save the editable.  When I use .toByte when concating with the string, it saved the bytes. I put a // by where the code is that is not working.
Here is my code.

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Comments")
        .setMessage("Enter Comments below")
        .setView(input)
        .setPositiveButton("Enter",  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            Editable value = input.getText();
            String string= value.toString()+ " "+ parent[groupPosition] + " "
```

//it does not combined value.toString() to the string.
                + kids[groupPosition][childPosition];

```
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                try {

                    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("repairs",
                            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                    fos.write(string.toString().getBytes());

                    fos.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried placing

```
Editable value = input.getText();
String string= value.toString()+ " "+ parent[groupPosition] + " ";
```

inside your try block? As it's currently written the `value` field is obtained when the OnClickListener is initialised and won't reflect the latest user input.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense to have it after onClick